# Compiler says that generic class method references itself directly or indirectly, but it's not

Tags: typescript, generics, self-reference

When I have the following code [(playground link)](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCIQDwBVoF5pgHYE8B80A3gFDRnSnkC2ApgC4AWA9gCYAUAlEZeeQE70ArnyzRGASwgA6SWyw0A7nAQcA3D2gBfDRtkRBEAA41gdAFzKIXQluLFNQA):

```
class Cls<T = any> {

    method() {
        return this.is(new Cls);
    }

    is(suspect: Cls) { }

}
```

Why do I get the following error?

> 'method' implicitly has return type 'any' because it does not have a return type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in one of its return expressions.

[EDIT] I know that I can add return type annotation, but why do I need to do this when it should be automatically deduced to be `void`.

Comment: Add parentheses after **new Cls** like **new Cls()**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you already know how to avoid the error (e.g., add a type annotation somewhere), but you want to know *why* the error is happening.  For that, we can look at a very similar reported issue, [microsoft/TypeScript#26623, a.k.a. "Compiler is unable to resolve return type of function even though it is returning function with known return type"](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26623).

This is basically a design limitation of TypeScript; the compiler thinks it needs to know the full type of the result of `new Cls()` before it can determine what `this.is(new Cls())` will return (even though *we* can easily see that this is `void` no matter what), and since the full type of `new Cls()` depends on the return type of `method()`, the compiler gives up.  This isn't quite the full story because classes often reference themselves indirectly, and inference usually just works. But something about the default type parameter `T = any` is being used in an unanticipated way.  You might think about opening your own issue in GitHub for more detailed information or for a fix, but I strongly suspect this will be deemed a design limitation or even a duplicate of the previously linked issue.

According to [a comment by the TypeScript development lead](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26623#issuecomment-415832255):

> The real issue here is that the two main operations the checker does - inference and error detection - occur at the "same time". You could imagine a different world where all inference happens, then all error checking happens, which would avoid this problem because the check of whether the argument type is assignable to the parameter type would only be part of the error-checking phase. But this would likely be at least twice as slow as the current implementation.
>
> There's no set practice that will avoid all circularity issues. The return type annotation is the best alternative for this example, I would say.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: No, I'm just a TypeScript enthusiast!

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly define the return type of the method **method()**. Make it like this: `method(): any`

Comment: I know that I can make return type explicit, but why do I have to? It should be trivially deduced to be `void`

Comment: If the return type is void, why would use the 'return' statement? It would be sufficient to use **method() {
        this.is(new Cls());
    }**